# Comunidação entre componente pai com filho

Tags: angular-8

Olá!
Tenho um componente pai o ConnectorWizardModalComponent e um componente filho ConnectorWizardComponent.
O componente filho faz extend do CdkStepper, e no componente pai tenho um array de objetos steps, que tem toda a informação que quero que seja exibido pelo componente filho, mas não consigo que eles se comuniquem. Vou postar o código para se entender melhor.
ConnectorWizardModalComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-connector-wizard-modal',
  templateUrl: './connector-wizard-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connector-wizard-modal.component.scss']
})

export class ConnectorWizardModalComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(ConnectorWizardComponent) connectorwizardComponent: ConnectorWizardComponent;
  @ViewChildren('linkRefs') linkRefs: QueryList<CdkStep>;

  contentReady = false;


  stepsRefs = [];


  selectedIndex;
  isEditable = false;

  steps: ConnectorStepModel[];
  currentComponent: number;
  @Output() closeModalEvent = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {


    this.steps = [
      {
        name: 'Select Engine',
        component: SelectEngineComponent,
        // stepControl: 'pending',
        descripition: 'select engine',
        icon: 'fa-share-alt',
        completed: false,
        data: new Step01Model(),
        outputs: {
          onNextStepEvent: data => this.onNextStep(data)
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Connector Configuration',
        component: ConnectorConfigIdentificationComponent,
        // stepControl: 'pending',
        descripition: 'select engine',
        icon: 'fa-share-alt',
        completed: false,
        data: new Step01Model(),
        outputs: {
          onPreviousStepEvent: data => this.onPreviousStep(data),
          onNextStepEvent: data => this.onNextStep(data)
        }

      },
      {
        name: 'Connector Configuration',
        component: ConnectorConfigCommunicationComponent,
        // stepControl: 'pending',
        descripition: 'select engine',
        icon: 'fa-share-alt',
        completed: false,
        data: new Step01Model(),
        outputs: {
          onPreviousStepEvent: data => this.onPreviousStep(data),
          onNextStepEvent: data => this.onNextStep(data),
        }

      },
    ];


    // this.currentComponent = this.steps[1];

    this.contentReady = true;

    // console.log('os filhos', this.linkRefs);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // this.openModal();


    // console.log('os filhoszzzz', this.linkRefs.toArray());
    // this.stepsRefs = this.linkRefs.toArray();
  }


  onCancel() {
    // redirect!
  }

  onPreviousStep(data) {
    this.connectorwizardComponent.previousStep();
  }

  onNextStep(data) {
    this.connectorwizardComponent.setComplete(data.isComplete);
    this.connectorwizardComponent.nextStep();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    // DO final work!!
  }

}
```

ConnectorWizard.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-connector-wizard',
  templateUrl: './connector-wizard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./connector-wizard.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [{ provide: CdkStepper, useExisting: ConnectorWizardComponent }]
})
export class ConnectorWizardComponent extends CdkStepper implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(dir: Directionality, changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(dir, changeDetectorRef);
  }
  ngOnInit() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    super.ngAfterViewInit();
  }


  stepState(stepIndex: number) {

    const step = this.steps.toArray()[stepIndex];

    if (stepIndex === this.selectedIndex) { return 'selected'; }
    if (step.completed) { return 'completed'; }
    if (step.interacted) { return 'warning'; }

    return 'pending';

  }

  nextStep(): void {
    if (this.selectedIndex < this.steps.length - 1) {
      this.selectedIndex++;
    }
  }

  previousStep(): void {
    if (this.selectedIndex > 0) {
      this.selectedIndex--;
    }
  }

  gotoStep(index: number): void {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

  setComplete(b: boolean): void {
    this.selected.completed = b;
  }

}
```

ConnectorWizard.html

```
<div content class="body bg-light w-100 h-100">
  <div class="row h-100">

    <div class="col-3 bg-white col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-3">
      <div leftbar class="h-100 bg-white">
        <div class="m-wizard__head text-center h-75 p-0">

          <div class="d-flex justify-content-center w-100 p-5">
              <div class="step stepper-horizontal" *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index;" [ngClass]="stepState(i)" (click)="gotoStep(i)">
                <div [ngClass]=" {'step-active border-primary rounded-circle': i === selectedIndex}"> {{i + 1}}</div>                                 <!-- rever esta condição (e trocar o selectedIndex pelo "step.selected") -->
              </div>  
          </div>  

          <div class="step-info w-75 h-50 m-auto pt-5">                      
            <i class="fa {{ steps.icon}} fa-8x text-secondary"></i>                                                                                           
            <h2 class="pt-4">{{ steps.label | translate}}</h2>                                                                                                     
            <span class="pt-4">{{ steps.description | translate}}</span>                                                          
          </div>        

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-9 pr-0 py-5 col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-9">
      <div rightbar class="right-bar-content">
        <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected.content"></ng-container>
      </div>
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="footerActions"></ng-template>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<ng-template #footerActions>
  <div class="actions" [ngClass]=" {'first-step-actions': selectedIndex === 0, 'forms-actions': selectedIndex > 0}">        
    <a *ngIf="selectedIndex === 0; else elseBlock" class="btn btn-secondary m-btn--icon" (click)="cancelProcess()">                               <!-- trocar o 0 por "primeiroStep" (e trocar o selectedIndex pelo "step.selected") -->
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-times wizard-btns-icon"></i>
        <span class="wizard-btns-text">
          {{ 'actions.cancel' | translate}}
        </span>
      </span>
    </a>
    <ng-template #elseBlock>
      <a *ngIf="selectedIndex !== 0" class="btn btn-secondary m-btn--icon ml-3" (click)="onPreviousStep()">                                       <!-- trocar o 0 por "primeiroStep" (e trocar o selectedIndex pelo "step.selected") -->
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-left wizard-btns-icon"></i>
          <span class="wizard-btns-text">
            {{ 'actions.previous' | translate}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </a>
      <button *ngIf="selectedIndex === 3" class="btn btn-primary m-btn--icon ml-3" (click)="finishProcess()">                                     <!-- trocar o 3 por "ultimoStep" (e trocar o selectedIndex pelo "step.selected") -->
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-check wizard-btns-icon"></i>
          <span class="wizard-btns-text">
            {{ 'labels.finish' | translate}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </button>
      <button *ngIf="selectedIndex < 3" class="btn btn-primary m-btn--icon ml-3" (click)="onNextStep()">                                          <!-- trocar o 3 por "ultimoStep" (e trocar o selectedIndex pelo "step.selected") -->
        <span>
          <i class="fa fa-arrow-right wizard-btns-icon"></i>
          <span class="wizard-btns-text">
            {{ 'actions.next' | translate}}
          </span>
        </span>
      </button>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

ConnectorWizardModal.html

```
<app-fullscreen-modal [onCloseAction]="closeModalAction">
    <div content class="body w-100 h-100">
      <app-connector-wizard linear>
        <cdk-step #linkRefs *ngFor="let step of steps; let stepIndex = index" [label]="step.name" [completed]="step.completed">
          <ng-container
            [ngComponentOutlet]="step.component"
            [ndcDynamicInputs]="{data: step.data}"
            [ndcDynamicOutputs]="step.outputs">
        </ng-container>
        </cdk-step>
      </app-connector-wizard>
    </div>
  </app-fullscreen-modal>
```

Como não há comunicação entre eles não consigo buscar as propriedades que preciso

```
<div class="step-info w-75 h-50 m-auto pt-5">                      
            <i class="fa {{ steps.icon}} fa-8x text-secondary"></i>                                                                                           
            <h2 class="pt-4">{{ steps.label | translate}}</h2>                                                                                                     
            <span class="pt-4">{{ steps.description | translate}}</span>                                                          
          </div>
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Ficou um pouco confusa sua pergunta, vc quer passar um **array de objetos** do componente pai para o componente filho?

Comment: Sim é essa a inteção

Comment: Mas isso é simples e o básico do Angular, utilizando  a diretiva **@Input()** vc consegue passar dados do componente pai para os filhos.

Comment: LeAndrade, não é tão simples assim...
O component filho faz extend do CdkStepper, que já tem um step que apenas conhece a propriedade label. E no meu componente pai tenho um step que é um array de objetos que possui outras propriedades, as quais preciso aceder no componente filho.

Comment: Vc quer iterar no array que vem do componente pai em qual elemento html no filho?

Comment: ```
<div class="step-info w-75 h-50 m-auto pt-5">                      
            <i class="fa {{ steps.icon}} fa-8x text-secondary"></i>                                                                                           
            <h2 class="pt-4">{{ steps.label | translate}}</h2>                                                                                                     
            <span class="pt-4">{{ steps.description | translate}}</span>                                                          
          </div>   
` ``